# How do I force my TFS 2010 Build to build all projects in the solution to be built in Debug or Release Mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

How do I force my TFS 2010 Build to build all projects in the solution to be built with Debug or Release Mode.  I'm looking to pass in an Argument into the workflow.  Do I need to use an MSBuild argument?

Seems like a very common thing to do, but I'm not able to find a straight-forward way of getting it done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Assumption: you are using the DefaultTemplate.xaml)

When you edit the build definition, you can locate the Process at the left side of the screen. Open the Items to build node and modify the Configurations to Build.

Comment: I had thought it was simple.  Thanks.