# VS publish to azure uses debug instead of release

Tags: azure, build

Is it just me, or Visual Studio 2012 with most recent update, package the current environment release upon publish, rather than the release specified in the publish settings?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: To force it to build in release mode I have to update the build definition as per this SO question: 
[How do I force my TFS 2010 Build to build all projects in the solution to be built in Debug or Release Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498224/how-do-i-force-my-tfs-2010-build-to-build-all-projects-in-the-solution-to-be-bui)

Not sure why I suddenly have to enforce this flag though??

It's not just you - I've been seeing the same thing for a week or so now and couldn't figure it out. When I remoted into my Azure vm I saw the the web.config it had published was just the debug one - yikes! Maybe it's not running the web.config transforms or something?