# Visual Studio publish uses debug mode instead of release

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, build, .net-4.5

The setup is this:

```
.NET 4.5
Visual Studio 2012 
Azure 2.0

one WebRole which hosts 2 sites:
   one MVC4 
   one WCF project
```

When I published the site to the cloud, it looked like it was working in debug mode.
I published it by right-clicking the cloud project, clicking publish and selecting the config version and the "release" build version when it prompted.

To check what happened, I opened up the `.cspkg` file by changing the extension to `.zip`, and checked the `.cssx` file in it (also changed the extension to `.zip`). This allowed me to see the `sitesroot/0` and `sitesroot/1` folders which had my website and service. These contained source code, even the `.csproj` files. To compare, I checked another solution on the cloud, which just had the `bin` folder and the only non-compiled code were the views and `.js` scripts and stylesheets.

I've made sure that the compilation element in the individual projects' configs looked like this:

```
<compilation debug="false">
```

Anyway, whatever I do it looks like it builds a package in debug mode. I'm completely in a loss, and I don't know what to look at anymore, since everything looks fine.

This question shows a related problem:
[VS publish to azure uses debug instead of release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006585/vs-publish-to-azure-uses-debug-instead-of-release)

But they're using TFS to automate the build and publish process, while I'm doing it manually.

Any tips or pointers would come in handy. Or at least a list of things to check and compare with other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit(lot) more digging, I've found the reason. It's the multiple sites on one web role that cause issues. Since the site code just gets copied into the `sitesroot` folder.

I've managed to solve the issue following the article here:

http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/multiple-sites-in-a-web-role/

What needs to be done is:

1. setup prebuild and postbuild events on each of the sites to take care of copying the built dlls into a custom build folder

   ```
   Pre (clears the custom build folder):
   rmdir "$(ProjectDir)..\YOUR-AZURE-PROJECT\Sites\$(ProjectName)" /S /Q

   Post (copies dlls to the custom build folder):
   %WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "$(ProjectPath)" /T:PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /P:Configuration=$(ConfigurationName);PreBuildEvent="";PostBuildEvent="";PackageAsSingleFile=false;_PackageTempDir="$(ProjectDir)..\YOUR-AZURE-PROJECT\Sites\$(ProjectName)"
   ```
2. change the sites elements in `ServiceDefinition.csdef` to point to the custom build folder

   ```
   <Sites>
       <Site name="WebSite" physicalDirectory="..\..\Sites\WebSite\">
           <Bindings>
               <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint2" />
           </Bindings>
       </Site>
   </Sites>
   ```